# IF AND, ELSE, IF AND, ELSE, IF AND, ELSE "0"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Please can someone help me nest the following into one formula:

1. `=IF(AND(Input!G50="",Input!H50=""),SUM(Input!F50:Input!F51))`
2. `=IF(AND(Input!F50="",Input!H50=""),SUM(Input!G50:Input!G51))`
3. `=IF(AND(Input!F50="",Input!G50=""),SUM(Input!H50:Input!H51))`
4. If all the above are empty, then 0

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since your criteria are mutually excluding one another you could simplify this to:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(F50:H50<>""),F50:H50+F51:H51)
```

If all cells in `F50:H50` are empty this will also return `0`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me @JvdV

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this guide to read more about nested IF statements. [https://www.makeuseof.com/excel-nested-if-statements/#:~:text=Nested%20IF%20Statements%20in%20Excel%20A%20nested%20IF,your%20conditions%20have%20been%20defined%20in%20the%20formula](https://www.makeuseof.com/excel-nested-if-statements/#:%7E:text=Nested%20IF%20Statements%20in%20Excel%20A%20nested%20IF,your%20conditions%20have%20been%20defined%20in%20the%20formula).
As far as I understood, seperating them with a comma is enough for excells program flow to execute them one by one.

NB: NOTICE that you have to use 3 closing brackets  ')' at then end cause we're opening 3 IF statements

```
    =IF(AND(Input!G50="",Input!H50=""),SUM(Input!F50:Input!F51),
    IF(AND(Input!F50="",Input!H50=""),SUM(Input!G50:Input!G51),
    IF(AND(Input!F50="",Input!G50=""),SUM(Input!H50:Input!H51))))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me @Brakke

Comment: I think you missed the 4th case of all empty return 0

Comment: Ah yes I missed the 4th case. No problem I see a complete answer has been provided. Good luck!